# Taxicab geometry distance calculations

Tags: geometry, lp-spaces, noneuclidean-geometry

As far as my understanding goes, taxicab geometry uses the lines of the coordinate plane to calculate distances. How does it affect the calculations when a point is not exactly on the intersection of the grid (like (1,2) or (4,5), and is instead somewhere in the middle? (1.5,3.2)?

Comment: Distance from $(x,y)$ to $(x', y')$ is $\left|(x-x')\right| + \left|(y-y')\right|$

Comment: @JohnWhite - so you would say to that when the point is in the middle the distance is greater. Is every point on the segment with endpoints (0,2) and (1,1) equidistant from the points (0,0) and (1,3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat it the same, as far as I know.  For example: if we want to find the $l_1$ (or taxicab) distance from $A=(1.2, 3.5)$ to $B=(4.1, 5.7)$, then

$d(A, B)=|4.1-1.2|+|5.7-3.5|=2.9+2.2=5.1$.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but I was asked to verify that every point on the segment with endpoints (0,2) and (1,1) is equidistant from the points (0,0) and (1,3), which would not seem to be the case about the points in the middle.

Comment: It is the case. The segment would be the set $\{(0+t,2-t):t\in[0,1]\}$. Then $d((0+t,2-t),(0,0))=t+2-t=2=1-t+3-(2-t)=d((0+t,2-t),(1,3))$ for any $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: We can write any point on the line segment as $(x, -x+2)$ for $x \in (0, 1)$.  Let $A=(x, -x+2), \ B=(0, 0),$ and $C=(1, 3)$.  Then $d(A, B)=|x|+|-x+2|$.  Since $0\leq x \leq 1$, then $d(A, B)=x+2-x=2$.  A similar calculation gives us that $d(A, C)=2$.  You should check this, but we'll use the fact that $0\leq x \leq 1$ (or specifically $|x-1|=1-x$).